# PHP Redis invalid DB index

Tags: php, redis, predis, phpredis

I'm connecting to Redis Labs to use redis for our application.

Here is my configurations:

```
$conf=[
 'scheme'=>'tcp',
 'host'=>'ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
 'port'=>12860,
 'database'=>'selector',
 'password'=>'redispassword'
];
```

Then I do this to load the predis library:

```
require "lib/predis/autoload.php";
```

After which I do this:

```
$client = new Predis\Client($conf);
```

Then I try to run a command:

```
$client->hset('comments',"comment:1","{json_encoded_data}");
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Predis\Connection\ConnectionException' with message '`SELECT` failed: ERR invalid DB index [tcp://cloud.redislabs.com:12860]' in /redis/lib/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
```

I've looked online and people say I should set the database as 0 however If I do that how do I use my selected database?

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `host` parameter is for your instance endpoint:

[image]

And RedisLabs only allows one database per instance, so you'll have no problem using `0` in the `database` parameter:

> That is exactly the reason why each of our Redis Cloud instances
>   allows using just one database (the default, 0-numbered database).
>   This ensures that any two databases in our service will never compete
>   on the resources of a single thread. **In fact, trying to use any
>   database other than 0 with our service should produce an error.**

[Source](https://support.redislabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/202215763-Can-I-have-multiple-databases-on-my-Redis-DB-Getting-ERR-invalid-DB-index-)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for answering this instead of me :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber it's no problem. Cool job!